# Visualization of Rhombus made of Radii and Chords

Tags: geometry

A rhombus is formed by two radii and two chords of a circle of diameter 20 units. What is the area of the rhombus?

Answer is 86.60

Ok I know i should provide a solution for this but my main problem is visualizing the problem in the first place. I really really don't see how two circles can form a rhombus? May I have some help drawing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's one circle.  The rhombus has four sides.  Two of the four sides are radii of the circle, and the other two are chords of the circle:

[image]

My diagram is a little crooked.  Remember that the four sides of a rhombus are always equal in length, and the radii of a circle are all equal in length.